# Create Process Steps in CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have been creating this steps process design in CSS the problem is I don't know how to create the arrows and make them still connect to each circle even when the screen has a different resolution.

[image]

This is what I've tried

```css
.process-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.process {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.process-step {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #34313c;
  border-color: #34313c;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-circle.active {
  background-color: #ff6350;
  border-color: #ff6350;
}
```

```html
<div class="process">
  <div class="process-row">
    <div class="process-step">

    </div>
    <div class="process-step">
      <span class="btn btn-circle active">Denied</span>
    </div>
    <div class="process-step">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top: 5px;"></div>
  <div class="process-row">
    <div class="process-step">
      <span class="btn btn-circle">Not Approved</span>
    </div>
    <div class="process-step">
      <span class="btn btn-circle">In Process</span>
    </div>
    <div class="process-step">
      <span class="btn btn-circle">Approved</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You would be better off using an svg here. Making this in CSS is hard, you may even need javascript for the positioning of the elements

Comment: i tried using images or svg but I cannot control the width of it to connect on the circles. And if the screen size is big it will not adjust.

Comment: maybe using a library like https://flowchart.js.org/ ? You can force it to re-render with different parameters if the screen size changes.

Answer (score 1):

I found out few demos for creating flow charts in css.
You can checkout this code pen - [`https://codepen.io/demonwhite/pen/Gxqpzv`](https://codepen.io/demonwhite/pen/Gxqpzv)

You can find more demos at - [`https://freefrontend.com/css-flowcharts/`](https://freefrontend.com/css-flowcharts)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in just CSS but it's not very flexible as you are creating the look only, not a proper structure.

This snippet has one process on row1 and 3 on row2, as in your example. It works by making everything proportional to some given unit. 1vmin is used in this case so it's as responsive as possible, fitting into narrow as well as wide devices.

CSS variables are used so it's easy to change something if required.

New calculations would have to be done if there are more or less processes to fit into a row - so it's not flexible in that sense, only in the responsive sense.

View the snippet in full page as (IDK why) some lines do not show in the mini snippet window. (They do show on different devices in Chrome emulator, however narrow the device).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  /* just for demo */
  width: auto;
  left: 50vw;
  top: 50vh;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: relative;
}

.processes {
  --u: 1vmin;
  /* the unit of measurement */
  --w: 20;
  /* width of an item */
  --h: 10;
  /* and its height */
  --bg: gray;
  --fs: 3;
  /* font size */
  --fc: white;
  /* font color */
  --lc: black;
  /* line color */
  --lw: 0.25;
  /* line width */
  /* horizontal line */
  --hl: linear-gradient(transparent 0, transparent calc(50% - (var(--lw) * var(--u) / 2)), var(--lc) calc(50% - (var(--lw) * var(--u) / 2)), var(--lc) calc(50% + (var(--lw) * var(--u) / 2)), transparent calc(50% + (var(--lw) * var(--u) / 2)), transparent 100%);
  /* a line */
  /* vertical line */
  --vl: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0, transparent calc(50% - (var(--lw) * var(--u) / 2)), var(--lc) calc(50% - (var(--lw) * var(--u) / 2)), var(--lc) calc(50% + (var(--lw) * var(--u) / 2)), transparent calc(50% + (var(--lw) * var(--u) / 2)), transparent 100%);
  /* a line */
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

[class^="row"] {
  width: 100vmin;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

[class^="row"]>* {
  /* each direct child of each row represents a process */
  width: calc(var(--w) * var(--u));
  height: calc(var(--h) * var(--u));
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: var(--bg);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  color: var(--fc);
  font-size: calc(var(--fs) * var(--u));
  margin: calc((var(--w) / 4) * var(--u));
  position: relative;
}

[class^="row"]>*::before,
[class^="row"]>*::after {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: calc(var(--fs) * var(--u));
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

[class^="row"]>*::after {
  color: transparent;
}

[class^="row"]>*::before {
  color: var(--lc);
}


/* set up the left and right lines and arrows */

.arrow-on-right::before,
.line-on-right::after,
.arrow-on-left::before,
.line-on-left::after {
  content: '\2bc7 ';
  width: 20vmin;
  background-image: var(--hl);
}

.arrow-on-right::before,
.line-on-right::after {
  left: 100%;
}

.arrow-on-left::before,
.line-on-left::after {
  right: 100%;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}


/* setup the top and bottom lines and arrows */

.arrow-on-top::before,
.line-on-top::after,
.arrow-on-bottom::before,
.line-on-bottom::after {
  content: '\2bc5';
  height: 15vmin;
  background-image: var(--vl);
}

.arrow-on-top::before,
.line-on-top::after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  rtop: -15vmin;
  bottom: 100%;
}

.arrow-on-bottom::before,
.line-on-bottom::after {
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="processes">
    <div class="row1">
      <div class="arrow-on-right line-on-left">p1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
      <div class="arrow-on-top">p2</div>
      <div class="arrow-on-left" style="--bg: orange;">p3</div>
      <div class="arrow-on-left line-on-top">p4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```